# $\sigma_N (g)'(x_0)=-\int_\pi^\pi F_N'(x_0-t)g(t)dt=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}F_N'(t)g(x_0-t)dt,$ where $F_N$ is the Fejér kernel.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

$$\sigma_N (g)'(x_0)=-\int_\pi^\pi F_N'(x_0-t)g(t)dt=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}F_N'(t)g(x_0-t)dt,$$ where $F_N$ is the Fejér kernel. Also we have $\int_{-\pi}^\pi F_N'(t)dt=0$.

To clarify notations, $\sigma_N(f)(x)=\frac{S_0(f)(x)+\cdots+S_{N-1}(f)(x)}{N}$, $S_n(f)=f*D_n$, $\sigma_N(f)(x)=(f*F_N)(x)$, $D_N(x)=\sum_{n=-N}^N e^{inx}$, and $F_N(x)=\frac{D_0(x)+\cdots+D_{N-1}(x)}{N}$.

Also, $g$ here is any continuous function that is differentiable at $x_0$.

The first paragraph is from a proof in Stein and Shakarchi's Fourier Analysis. But I don't understand why we have the identity and why we have $\int_{-\pi}^\pi F_N'(t)dt=0$. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: $F_N$ it periodic so the mean value of its derivative is $0$. And $S_n(f)(x) = f \ast D_n(x) = \sum_{m = -n}^n c_m e^{i m x} $ where $c_m = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\infty f(t) e^{-imt}dt$ by definition

Comment: If $g$ is extended periodically, then $F_N'(x_0-t)g(t)$ is periodic with period $2\pi$. So the integral is the same over any $2\pi$ length interval, which gives $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}F_N'(x_0-t)g(t)dt=\int_{x_0-\pi}^{x_0+\pi}F_N'(x_0-t)g(t)dt=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}F_N(-t)dtg(x_0+t)$. Then substitute $s=-t$.

Comment: @user1952009 Can you explain why if a function is periodic, the mean value of its derivative is $0$? I don't know where this fact comes from.

Comment: $f(2\pi)-f(0) = \int_0^{2\pi} f'(t)dt$